# Linux VirtualBox cache disk writes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows 10 guest in VirtualBox on an Ubuntu 15.04 host. Being Windows, it generates a lot of disk activity which slows down my host system and places excessive wear on my otherwise usually-idle hard disk. Is it possible to make VirtualBox, or even Linux itself, cache disk writes so that disk changes are only committed like, once every 15 seconds? I have looked at throttling disk usage bandwidth, but that is likely to only slow down the virtual machine below usable limits.